# What happens to items worn when stepping into the Ethereal Plane using the "Etherealness" spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment, ethereal-plane

Etherealness reads:

> You step into the border regions of the Ethereal Plane, in the area where it overlaps with your current plane (PHB, page 238)

This never specifies whether worn items become ethereal along with yourself, but it also includes that

> You ignore all objects and effects that aren't on the Ethereal Plane, allowing you to move through objects you perceive on the plane you originated from. (PHB, page 238)

So, would any worn or carried items such as weapons or clothes become ethereal with you, or would they stay behind?

Comment: Related: "[What qualifies for the target of a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77775)" and "[If I am holding an item before I cast Blink, will it move with me through the Ethereal Plane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143294)" and a little bit this Q/A: "[Can you leave objects behind in the ethereal plane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124596)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### They come with you

Consider:

> You step into the [border regions of the Ethereal Plane], ...
>
> You step into the [bathroom], ...
>
> You step into the [wagon], ...
>
> You step into the [mind of someone strange enough to think that when you step somewhere you leave your clothes behind], ...

Apart from the last one, your stuff comes with you.